# delete duplicate rows mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query, but it deletes all the rows "info" instead of deleting only the duplicate ones. What am i doing wrong?

```
$db->setQuery("DELETE t1 FROM #__rsform_submission_values t1 
                INNER JOIN #__rsform_submission_values t2 
                WHERE t1.SubmissionValueId > t2.SubmissionValueId AND t1.FieldName = 'info' AND t1.SubmissionId = '".$subId."'");
$db->query();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
```

Comment: How does this even run, you don't have an ON statement in your inner join?

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? It doesn't use table names beginning with `#`.

Comment: @Magisch As far as I know, `INNER JOIN` without `ON` is the same as writing just `,` instead of `INNER JOIN`, at least in some RDBMS. In other words, I assume that this just is the cross product of the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed this query is somehow working, you tell it to remove any row (with name 'info' and some submission value id) for which it can find another row that has a `SubmissionValueId` that is lower.

You need to think about what it means for a pair of rows to be duplicates. E.g. if they have the same `FieldName`. Suggestion: add `AND t2.FieldName = 'info'`, if that's what you meant.

There seems to be more to improve about this query, but I would start with the essence of it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a `JOIN` condition.  I am guessing:

```
DELETE rsv
    FROM #__rsform_submission_values rsv INNER JOIN 
         #__rsform_submission_values rsv2
         ON rsv2.SubmissionId = rsv.SubmissionId AND
            rsv2.FieldName = rsv.FieldName
    WHERE rsv.SubmissionValueId > rsv2.SubmissionValueId AND
          rsv.FieldName = 'info' AND rs1.SubmissionId = ?;
```

You should learn to use parameterized queries, rather than munging query strings.  That is why I replaced the id value with `?`.